# Display Single Record For Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a view to display a value based on the number of existing documents meeting a condition. If that number is greater than one, then 'Yes'. Else 'No'.

Here is my SQL:

```
with docStatus as
(
select c.PersonID, d.Status as dStatus, d.Source as Source, count(d.Status) as rDoc
from Documents d with (nolock)
inner join PersonDocuments d1 with (nolock) on d1.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
inner join Person c with (nolock) on c.PersonID = d1.PersonID
group by c.PersonID, d.Status, d.Source
)
select distinct(
    case
       when rDoc > 1 then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
    end ) as MissingDocuments,
    docStatus.PersonID
from docStatus
where dStatus = 12
and Source in (2, 3, 9, 11)
order by docStatus.PersonID
```

When I run the entire query (using `select *` rather than the `distinct`), this is what it looks like:

[image]

Due to the row with 1 `rDoc` value, my output when running with `disticnt` duplicates the row listing both. This makes sense:

[image]

**Question**

Is it possible that if *any row* contains an `rDoc` value > 1 that it return a single row with a 'Yes' value, rather than one row with 'Yes' and one with 'No'? I would still need a 'No' value if no other row exists with an `rDoc` > 1.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. To make things clearer, remove the redundant parentheses around the case expression, i.e. `select distinct case ... end as MissingDocuments, ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and some conditional logic:

```
select PersonID,
       (case when max(rDoc) > 1 then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end) as MissingDocuments
from docStatus
where dStatus = 12 and Source in (2, 3, 9, 11)
group by PersonId
order by PersonID;
```

I should note that this assumes that `rDoc` is not `NULL`.  A problem occurs if *all* values for a person are `NULL`.  This is easily fixed, if you know what the logic should be (the above would return `'No'` in that case).

Comment: Great answer, I'm sad this didn't occur to me. Thank you!